# how can I change the locale shown on the login screen of lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, login, screen, locale

I just installed Lubuntu 20.04 in VirtualBox and applied available updates/upgrades. It all works well enough but even though I've checked the locale is correct for UK english, the login screen still shows USA English with USA flag and cannot be changed. Is that a bug ?
Screenshot shows the issue for UK

[image]

```
cat /etc/default/keyboard gives:
# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE
# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.
XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="gb"
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBOPTIONS=""
BACKSPACE="guess"
```

Comment: https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/3/3.2/3.2.9/locale.html?highlight=locale however that will change LXQt (or your session once logged in rather than `sddm`).  The greeter config (`sddm`) is found at https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/3/3.1/3.1.9/sddm_configuration.html?highlight=sddm ; sorry I've not played with changing languages/locales (I don't see US flag though, but cannot recall why; I do remember if no region is specified New York NY USA is used by default)

Comment: I already configured the locale for post login

Comment: What would I add to /etc/sddm.conf can change the prelogin locale ?

Comment: If I get a chance (and remember) I'll look tomorrow. I booted a QA-test install and yes like yours it showed a US flag (for my AU english); I do recall the patch hitting the system that caused flag to show, but I'm too tired now & heading for bed. (I'll plan to compare with my current system (*where I don't see it I believe*) tomorrow, it's 20.10 nothing relevant has changed)

Comment: Can you edit your question and show the output from the command: `cat /etc/default/keyboard`